# setting up ssh-keys for bitbucket account (with mac osx)

Tags: macos, bitbucket, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I have a `BitBucket` account. Despite setting up the `ssh key` on the computer and then adding it on my `bitbucket` account, I fail at connecting:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:my-account/myrepo.git 
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I did the following:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh

$ ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/my-key -N ''

$ vim config
Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-key

$ ls -l
-rw-------  1 me  ...   229 Jul  8 15:50 config
-rw-------  1 me  ...  1679 Jul  8 14:07 my-key
-rw-r--r--  1 me  ...   411 Jul  8 14:07 my-key.pub
```

Then I added the content of my-key.pub in my bitbucket account's `ssh key`s. Then I retried cloning my `repository`:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:my-account/myrepo.git 
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I repeated the identical procedure on another machine, it worked:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:my-account/myrepo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/me/.ssh/myrepo/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
```

I need to do the same on my first machine now. 
As a last resort, I followed some advises on the net using the ssh-agent:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-key
```

But still no luck:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:my-account/myrepo.git 
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have no idea what is different on the first machine, why does it reject my request?

---

EDIT 1

Of course I tried doing it the very basic way, as suggested by `D.Samchuk`:

Generating the id_rsa

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
enterx3
```

Copied the exact content of the key

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And I added id_rsa.pub's content in my BitBucket account's ssh keys.

Git clone will still not allow me to access the repository, whit the same output error message as above.

---

EDIT 2

I have no idea maybe it is related to mac configurations? Since The other machine is a `redhat linux` I just wondered but couldn't find any reported similar issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  Try https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree with you sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. As I delved deeper in the issue I found it is absolutely not related to `ssh` keys but to missing repository as the error message suggested. It was all about experimenting the global config using `git config --global` that messed up my git configuration on that computer. I detailed my steps in another thread here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294780/git-retains-remote-information-from-a-deleted-repository/294809#294809.

Answer (score 15):

just do following:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

name: id_rsa

passphrase: just press enter twice to avoid print keyword everytime you connect

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

copy output

open bitbucket --> profile --> bitbucket settings --> add ssh key --> paste your output

Comment: That's the very first thing I did, before trying making my own config file, with separate ssh keys. Nonetheless I removed my ssh keys, my ssh config file, I followed your step, `git clone` wont let me access the repository, same error.

Comment: This didn't work. I just followed the official guide https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-personal-ssh-keys-on-macos/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a passphrase for the ssh key you shouldn't need the ssh-agent

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/